# replace + with space in html Gmail/Android chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, gmail, mailto

Hi i have web application which uses mailto like

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&amp;cc=someone_else@example.com&amp;body=This%20is%20the%20body" class="">Send email</a>
```

but no meter what i do it alway replace space with + sign [image]

Comment: duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172338/android-email-replaces-space-with-plus

Comment: Foaster that's different question the link you sended is about java programing and tell us about how to use intents but my question is about html .

Comment: I have the same problem. We test it on iOS and there it's working on both browsers (Chrome and Safari)

Comment: @WooCaSh yes its working on ios but in android its not working .dont know why .

Comment: @Noman, I know it hasn't been that long, but could try testing this again on Android with the latest Chrome and latest Gmail. I am seeing still the same problem with the +'s, but now the body=value does not even populate the body of the composer. I've create a test page to test as many cases as possible. http://jsbin.com/roxage/2/ - pick one that has a BODY=VALUE

Comment: Further testing, looks like the BODY not getting populated only happens on Gmail 5.0, Gmail 4.9 and Outlook do not have this issue, but still seeing the +'s instead of spaces

Comment: @bentael same issue here. no solution soo far.

Comment: Lol... 9 years later... I am here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to decode your String

just use [Uri.encode(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html).

```
subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
subject.setText(Uri.encode(WhatEverYourStringVarIs));
```

This will help you to decode the URIencode.

If you mean the PHP (HTML) Issue just do the same:

```
$encodeString = urlencode($encodeString);
echo $encodedString;
```

So the String will displayed proper.
See this [url encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php).

Okay, but when i'm read your Question the third time: You can use Spaces in these HTML case. It is an Android Bug. Just use this:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This is the subject&amp;cc=someone_else@example.com">Send Mail</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rising from the dead after 8 years...

you can (as far as I tested) just leave the spaces in the string. The browser will handle the conversion for URL purposes (which was probably the reason the spaces were converted into plus signs... browser was interpreting them literally.